# Get two rows in two columns from left join mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I've two tables which structure and data is given below.

```
table1
id, name
1, abc
2, xyz


table2
id, table1_id, type, other_name
1, 1, 1, hello
2, 1, 2, world
3, 2, 1, wonder
4, 2, 2, this world
```

Need result with rows having columns like:

```
table1.id, table1,name, table2.other_name where table2.type=1, table2.other_name where table2.type=2
```

I've tried:

```
SELECT
table1.id, table1,name,
IF(table2.type=1, table2.other_name,NULL) AS current_name,
IF(table2.type=2, table2.other_name,NULL) AS previous_name
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.table1_id = table1.id
GROUP BY table1.id;
```

But it returning like:

```
1, abc, hello, NULL
2, xyz, wonder, NULL
```

Whereas I would like to have result like:

```
1, abc, hello, world
2, xyz, wonder, this world
```

Please help guys!

Comment: What you try to do? You are using "group by" clause, but no aggregate functions for table1.name, current_name, previous_name

Comment: Can u please explain which I should use have result which I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You should use aggregate functions, which working with multi-rows with "group by", also move table1.name under "group by".

```
SELECT table1.id, 
       table1.name,
       max(IF(table2.type=1, table2.other_name, NULL)) AS current_name,
       max(IF(table2.type=2, table2.other_name, NULL)) AS previous_name
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.table1_id = table1.id
GROUP BY table1.id, table1.name;
```